# How to add padding in printing table in F#?

Tags: f#

I'm trying to print a factorial talbe:

**Input**:   an int n.

**Output**:  a table of factorial results from 1! to n!.

Here is what I did:

```
let toBigInt (n: int) = bigint(n)  // Convert an "int" to a "bigint".

// Factorial with bigint support:
let fac n = 
    [1..n] 
    |> List.map toBigInt 
    |> List.reduce (*) 

let printFacTable n =
    let listNum = [1 .. n]
    let listFac = listNum |> List.map fac
    let numFacPair = List.zip listNum listFac
    for (k, v)  in numFacPair
        do printfn "%d ! = %A" k v
```

The result:

```
> printFacTable 12;;
1 ! = 1
2 ! = 2
3 ! = 6
4 ! = 24
5 ! = 120
6 ! = 720
7 ! = 5040
8 ! = 40320
9 ! = 362880
10 ! = 3628800
11 ! = 39916800
12 ! = 479001600
val it : unit = ()
```

The result is fine. I would like to vertical align the `! =` by adjust paddings in front of the `!`. Let's say this program accept up to 8 digits number as input. I guess the padding should be:

```
let padding = 8 - eachNum.length
```

But I don't know how to put it into the program block. Any idea?

Comment: Why I got downvoted? Is that because my question is too simple? As a beginner, I've already tried hard to solve the problem.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I'd wager a guess that it was because the question was answerable by reading the documentation, which should be the _first_ step. The question is well formed though, there's nothing intrinsically wrong with it. :-]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As detailed in the [`Printf` module documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370560.aspx), you simply need to specify the width of the field:

```
printfn "%8d ! = %A" k v
```

Comment: Ah, that's so straight forward! Thanks for the documentation link.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
do printfn "%8d ! = %A" k v
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it's better to format on the left side:

```
for (k, v)  in numFacPair
    do printfn "%-2d ! = %A" k v
```

Then printFacTable 12:

```
1  ! = 1
2  ! = 2
3  ! = 6
4  ! = 24
5  ! = 120
6  ! = 720
7  ! = 5040
8  ! = 40320
9  ! = 362880
10 ! = 3628800
11 ! = 39916800
12 ! = 479001600
```

Link: http://ideone.com/gJeK0B

Comment: When the input number increased to 3 digits, we need to increase the indent to `%-3d`, so I guess it is better to set it to `%-8d`. It's also good to know `ideone.com`. Thanks!